# What do these parameter definitions mean in python?

Tags: python

Many different representation of parameters in python  such as :

```
urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])

urllib2.build_opener([handler, ...])

cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(filename, delayload=None, policy=None)


urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])
```

and

```
urllib2.urlopen(url,data,timeout)
```

Does the first one means all the url ,data and timeout can be passed as list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that the parameter in second method is a list

This is incorrect. Square brackets in command/function documentation denote optional parameters. Note that in Python order of parameters *does* matter, so you'll need to use keyword arguments to omit parameters in the middle.

```
urllib2.urlopen(someurl, somedata, sometimeout)
urllib2.urlopen(someurl)
urllib2.urlopen(someurl, somedata)
urllib2.urlopen(someurl, timeout=sometimeout)

urllib2.build_opener()
urllib2.build_opener(handler1)
urllib2.build_opener(handler1, handler2)
urllib2.build_opener(handler1, handler2, handler3)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's standard notation for optional arguments... ie you may pass data, optionally followed by timeout, or as you have its name, pass timeout without data using timeout=...